# How to get a video networkUrl from Firebase Storage, without App Check token

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

I understand in order to play a video from the web in BetterPlayer, you need the networkUrl, so is the networkUrl the Firebase Storage downloadUrl

```
final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
Future<String> downloadUrl() async {
  final downloadUrl =
      await storage.ref("User_uploadVideo/videoplayback.mp4").getDownloadURL();
  return downloadUrl;
}
```

If so, how do you get the URL successfully? My code runs into an error in the debug console saying `W/NetworkRequest( 5351): No App Check token for request.` I haven't enabled app check, and have disabled Firebase Storage rules for development.

**Update**: when I try and only print out what is fetched from cloud storage I get `Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthenticated] User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again.` this doesn't add up due to me making my rules public